# How do I get a vagrant box running with Apache, MYSQL, and specific PHP version?

Tags: vagrant

I've been using the Homestead virtual box for developing with Laravel for some time now and love it. I simply followed the very clear [Homestead tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) which got me started. However, I'm still mostly in the dark about how to set up and run custom Vagrant boxes, and have found the tutorials to be severely lacking beyond *Look how amazing Vagrant is compared to WAMP* and how to do '*vagrant up*'.

**What I can do:**

- Initialize a vagrant box
- Download a preconfigured box from vagrant cloud
- set the config.vm.network in the Vagrant file to an IP address and match that IP address to a domain in my hosts file
- set config.vm.provision to install Apache
- set config.vm.synced_folder to map a specific folder to the VB

**What I don't know how to do:**

- Install MYSQL and setup connections for my database tool (HeidiSQL)
- Map and select the public folder for a project (ie. that contains the
  files to be loaded when I visit that URL)
- Select which version of PHP I want to install (I need to be running
  php5.3 for a specific project)

If anyone could give me some pointers, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: look at [puphpet](https://puphpet.com) you can configure your vagrant box with many different options and download a Vagrantfile + puppet provisioning so you get a box with all soft/version running

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful, although it seems to only allow PHP 5.4 +, which means it's not going to help for my specific case- which has to be PHP 5.3

Comment: argh miss that ! you can always give a try and change the config.yaml to attempt to instance version 5.3 but setting `version: '56'` in php block